# Passing refs from Component to Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am not sure if passing refs would be the best thing to do but it's kinda what I have set-out to do tell me if there is a better option..

So I am trying to have an onClick of a nav link, scroll down to the the div "contactForm".

App.js

```
import ContactForm from './components/ContactForm'
import ParllaxPage from './components/ParllaxPage'
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar'
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {


  return (

    < div cssClass="App" >
      <body>
        <span><NavigationBar /></span>
        <ParllaxPage cssClass="parallax-wrapper" />
        <ParllaxPage cssClass="parallax-wrapper parallax-pageOne" />
        <ContactForm />
      </body >
    </div >
  );
}

export default App;
```

I was trying to use forwardRef but I am not sure that I was doing it correctly so...

NavigationBar.js

```
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import App from "../App";
import { Nav, Navbar, Form, FormControl, Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const ContactFormRef = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
 <ContactForm className="contactForm" ref={ref}>
  {props.children}
 </ContactForm>
));

const scrollToRef = (ref) => ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });

const NavigationBar = () => {
 const ref = React.forwardRef(ContactFormRef);

 return (
  <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
   <Navbar.Brand href="#home">A1 Gutters</Navbar.Brand>
   <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="b casic-navbar-nav" />
   <Nav className="mr-auto">
    <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link href="#" onClick={console.log(ref)}>
     Contact
    </Nav.Link>
   </Nav>
  </Navbar>
 );
};

export default NavigationBar;
```

I don't think the other files really need to be shown, I am just trying to get the className out of the ContactForm component so I can scroll to it onClick.. I currently just have a console.log in the onClick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Hooks` will simplify here.

1. Have state variable for `gotoContact` and ref for `contactRef`
2. Add click handler for navigation link `contact`
3. Add useEffect hook and when ever use click on contact and ref is available (value in ref.current) then call the scroll to view)

```
import ContactForm from "./components/ContactForm";
import ParllaxPage from "./components/ParllaxPage";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const NavigationBar = ({ onClickContact }) => {
  return (
    <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
      <Navbar.Brand href="#home">A1 Gutters</Navbar.Brand>
      <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="b casic-navbar-nav" />
      <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
        <Nav.Link href="#" onClick={() => onClickContact()}>
          Contact
        </Nav.Link>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [gotoContact, setGotoContact] = useState(false);
  const contactRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (gotoContact && contactRef.current) {
      contactRef.current.scrollIntoView();
      setGotoContact(false);
    }
  }, [gotoContact, contactRef.current]);

  return (
    <div cssClass="App">
      <body>
        <span>
          <NavigationBar onClickContact={() => setGotoContact(true)} />
        </span>
        <ParllaxPage cssClass="parallax-wrapper" />
        <ParllaxPage cssClass="parallax-wrapper parallax-pageOne" />
        <div ref={contactRef}>
          <ContactForm />
        </div>
      </body>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to get this working for on click, but it doesn't really "scroll" but I am sure I can get those things fixed, and the navbar disappears but it is what it is, I can figure something out. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should identify the div "contactForm" with an id and have an anchor tag point to it:

```
<a href="#contactForm"></a>
<div id="contactForm"></div>
```

You can add `scroll-behaviour: smooth` to the body in CSS

Answer (score 0):

No need to create a separate `ContactFormRef` wrapper. Simply use `React.forwardRef` in `ContactForm` itself. Those not passing a ref will not have to know it forwards refs.

Then, remember to further pass the ref received to a native element or use `useImperativeHandle` hook to add methods to it without passing it further down.

```js
 const ref = React.forwardRef(ContactFormRef)
```

This is wrong.

You should do it the same as with native components:

```js
const ref = useRef()

return <ContactForm ref={ref} >
    // etc
</ContactForm>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering the ContactFormRef, so the reference points no nothing!

App.js should be like:

```js
...
const App = () => {
  const myNestedRefRef=React.useRef();
  return (
    ...
      <NavigationBar contactRef={myNestedRefRef}/>
    ...
      <ContactForm ref={myNestedRefRef} />
    ...
  );
}
...
```

ContactForm.js

```js
...
function ContactForm=React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
 <form ref={ref}>
  ...
 </form>
));
```

NavigationBar.js

```js
const NavigationBar = ({contactRef}) => {
 return (
  ...
    <Nav.Link href="#" onClick={console.log(contactRef)}>
  ...
 );
};
```

### Consider that

If the `<ContactForm/>` hasn't been rendered yet, the ref will look like `{current:null}`